# Error loading watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

Is there a way to install an earlier version of watir-webdriver including dependencies?

I've been running watir-webdriver for a while now, but just ran into problems today when installing on a new Windows environment.

The error is on the require "watir-webdriver". The first error line indicates that ruby is unable to load ffi

```
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- ffi_c (LoadError)
```

It looks like the problem may be with the combination of gems, so am including the versions here:

```
bigdecimal (1.2.4)
childprocess (0.5.3)
ffi (1.9.5 x86-mingw32)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
multi_json (1.10.1)
psych (2.0.5)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
rubyzip (1.1.6)
selenium-webdriver (2.43.0)
test-unit (2.1.3.0)
watir-webdriver (0.6.11, 0.6.10)
websocket (1.2.1)
```

Comment: have you tryes to run the script with `bundle exec ./your_script`?

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/273) was raised and closed against `watir-webdriver`, and the closing note points to `ffi`.  Check out the [issue](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/368) against `ffi` where `gem -rdevkit install ffi --platform=ruby ffi` is a suggested workaround.  Your mileage may vary...

Answer (score 0):

If you know of a version that worked in the past, you can simple remove the current version and install an old one with the -v flag for gem install.

For example,

```
gem uninstall watir-webdriver
gem install watir-webdriver -v '= 0.4.0'
```

You can find the different available version on [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org/gems/watir-webdriver/versions) It will automatically install the proper dependencies.